# If $E= A\cup B \cup C$ and $E$ is connected , where $A$ and $B$ are disconnected and $C$ is connected, then $A \cup C$ is connected.

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces, connectedness

If $E= A\cup B \cup C$ and $E$ is connected in a metric space $(X,d)$, where $A$ and $B$ are disconnected and $C$ is connected, then $A \cup C$ is connected.

If we consider that $A \cup C$ is not connected, then $A \cup C = M \cup N$, where $M$ and $N$ are non-empty and disconnected in $X$. And since $C$ is connected then it must contain in one of $M$ or $N$. Then hoe to bring a contradiction?

Thank You.

Comment: That can't be correct? Take E to be a square, A a pair of opposite sides (including the vertices), B the other pair and C one of the vertices. In that case, everything is satisfied but of course, $A\cup C$ is not connected...

Comment: Perhaps $A\cup B$ needs to be disconnected.

Comment: @MattSamuel Hmm, that's not enough either, take $A=[-2,-1]\cup [1,2], B=(-1,0)\cup (0,1), C=\{0\}$...

Comment: What are the openness conditions on the spaces for examples?

Comment: Maybe the OP would clarify things a bit..?

Comment: is separated and disconnected have same meaning